# Pyodbc + SQLA - Communication link failure

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am having issues when reconnecting to Azure MSSQL after inactive time.
My SQLA connection code is

```
class DB:
def __init__(self):
    self.engine = create_engine(
        "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params), 
        pool_pre_ping=True, 
    )
    self.connection = self.engine.connect()
    self.session = scoped_session(
        sessionmaker(
            bind=self.engine, 
            autocommit=False, 
            autoflush=False,
        )
    )
```

I have enabled pool_pre_ping as stated [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic) in SQLA documentation, but still, I am getting this error after some time of inactivity.

Error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\r\n (10060) (SQLEndTran); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10060)')
```

Can this error be avoided within engine/session creation or is the only option to just wrap queries in try: except pyodbc.OperationalError: ?